# How can I find $\det(A)/\det(B)$, when individual determinants blow up

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant, volume

I am interested in the quantity: $\frac{\det(A)}{\det(B)}$ of positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$.

The problem I am running into now is that for large $A$,$B$, (around $200 \times 200$), the determinants of $A$ and $B$ are above 
the machine precision (I'm using *R* to find the determinants) and I run into errors with Infinity.

I want to utilize the formula, for $A$, $B$ that are $n \times n$:

$$\frac{\det(A)}{\det(B)} = \frac{\frac{1}{k^n}\det(A)}{\frac{1}{k^n}\det(B)}
                        = \frac{\det(\frac{1}{k}A)}{\det(\frac{1}{k}B)}$$

However, I tried a whole bunch of $k$, $k(n)$ but I still run into $\infty$ (either $\infty$ or $\frac{1}{\infty}$) problems.

The range for the elements in $A$ and $B$ is around $[-1000,1000]$.

Any input or insight would be appreciated!!!

Comment: A "stable" way to compute the $\det(A)$. Compute a stable decomposition of $A$, like a Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ and compute $\det(A) = \det(L)^2$.

Comment: What happens if you factor out the maximum value of each column?

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you so much!! I went through each of the columns of A and B and factored out column by column the maximum value of that column in A and B. Results improved substantially. I think my problem is solved!

Comment: @user251257 but if $\det(A) = \det(L)^2$, wouldn't $\det(L)$ blow up also?

Comment: $\det(L)$ is just the product of the diagonal elements. That's as stable as it gets. I am not sure how R computes $\det$. Probably in a similar way. What exactly blows up?

Comment: The determinant is multiplicative, so $\det(A)/\det(B) = \det(B^{-1}A)$, so you could try computing $\det(B^{-1}A)$ instead. Also, the best way to compute $B^{-1}A$ is probably as the matrix with columns $d_i$ such that $B d_i = a_i$, where $a_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$.

Comment: Notice that constant scaling usually as no effect on stability due to floating point arithmetic in computer. If everything fails, compute eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ and $B$ and their determinants as product of eigenvalues.

Comment: Do $A$ and $B$ have some structure?

Comment: @user251257 I believe they're both positive definite. The determinant blows up, as in it goes to like 10^300 and more, and the machine cannot handle that anymore. It's not really a problem with precision, because when I take the ratio of two really big numbers, I don't really care about each of their individual precision. It's the fact that if I compute the determinants individually first, I get inf/inf.

Comment: @A.P. genius! I will try this right now!!

Comment: @A.P. thank you so much...why didn't I see this?? This is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant is multiplicative, so $\det(A)/\det(B)=\det(B^{−1}A)$. You could try computing $\det(B^{−1}A)$ directly, instead, as it will likely be smaller than $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$.

Also note that the best way to compute $B^{−1}A$ is probably as the matrix with columns $d_i$ such that $Bd_i=a_i$, where $a_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$.

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thanks a lot!